# Visual glitch in NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm highlighting a text in NSTextView. Nothing fancy, just custom background and foreground colors for some ranges.

```swift
guard let textStorage = textView.textStorage else { return }
let str = """
var invariant = require('fbjs/lib/invariant');
var warning = require('fbjs/lib/warning');
"""

let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [.font: NSFont(name: "Menlo", size: 11.0)!] )
textStorage.setAttributedString(attrStr)

for layoutManager in textStorage.layoutManagers {

    layoutManager.addTemporaryAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: NSColor.darkGray, forCharacterRange: NSRange(location: 47, length: 43))    
    layoutManager.addTemporaryAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.red, forCharacterRange: NSRange(location: 69, length: 18))
}
```

This results in a thin vertical white line which is drawn at the end of the `.foregroundColor` range. Why does this line appear? How can I get rid of it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0l0n.png)

Comment: Seems like a legitimate bug in either the layout with fractional widths, or in the drawing due to them. I expect it changes at different font sizes. If my hunches are right, this is not something quick and easy to fix. File a bug report and/or ask DTS.

Comment: @seth you are absolutely right. Different font size makes the glitch appear at different position.

Comment: I am struggling with the exact same problem. Did you ever find any solution for this?